# put comma after every number separated by space in matrix

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to transform this kind of string `matrix(1 0 0 1 961 3040.5)`

into `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 961, 3040.5)` with PHP

I tried to get numbers only with `preg_replace` and then add commas with `str_split` but the problem is that with this approach I don't know where is the ending of a number to put comma in the right position.

Any ideas?

Comment: replace all occurrences of space with `, ` ?

Comment: Yes, your input is rather simple and can be handled with `$s = str_replace(" ", ", ", $s)`. Or is it part of a longer string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the following way :

```
$regex = '/\s/';
$matrix = 'matrix(1 0 0 1 961 3040.5)';
$subst = ', ';
$result = preg_replace($regex, $subst, $matrix);
echo $result;  // matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 961, 3040.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use replace regex like `/\s/,/g`

**JavaScript Code**

```js
var str = "matrix(1 0 0 1 961 3040.5)";

var str = str.replace(/\s/g, ",");

console.log(str);
```